# Why is the vertical scroll getting stuck in mobile view?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, vertical-scrolling

The webpage, when in mobile view, is getting stuck when I attempt to scroll vertically. In `@media screen and (max-width: 952px) {}` I have `overflow-x: hidden;`, `width: 100%;`, and `position: absolute;` set in order to prevent horizontal scrolling because the mobile nav bar is hidden to the right. I've attempted to add `overflow-y: scroll;` and `overflow-y: auto;` to the code and even added `!important` and I am still experience vertical scroll issues.

You can view a live version of the webpage at [jacpel5.dreamhosters.com](http://jacpel5.dreamhosters.com)

HTML for the 'Photography' page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Jacki Leigh - Photography</title> 
            <!-- title appears in browser tab -->
        <link href="myStyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
            <!-- linking to myStyleSheet.css file for styling --> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/swe6opx.css">
            <!-- font family "Operetta 8" -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/opw2jnd.css">
            <!-- font family "Relation Two" -->
        <link href="photos/favicon.png" rel="icon" type="image/gif" sizes="16x16">
            <!-- linking to the favicon -->
        <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
            <!-- UTF-8 is the default character set for HTML5 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <!-- viewport gives browser instructions on how to control the page's dimensions and scaling -->
            <!-- width=device-width sets the width of the page to follow the screen-width of the device --->
            <!-- 1.0 scale sets the initial zoon level when the page is first loaded by the browser -->
        <meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
            <!-- allows the spider of a search engine to index the whole website -->
        <meta name="keywords" content="Jacki Leigh, photography, light painting, long exposure, music, music photography, portrait photography, portraits, panasonic, camera, photos, live music photography, live music, freelance photographer, freelance, photographer, freelance photography">
        <meta name="description" content="Jacki Leigh is an LA based freelance photographer. She specializes in concert photography and light painting.">
            <!-- Use no more than 200 characters. This is the description that appears in the search results on search engines -->
        <meta name="author" content="Jacki Leigh Designs">
    </head>
    <body>

    <header>
        <div class="container">

            <a href="index.html">
            <img src="photos/logo.png" alt="Jacki Leigh Logo" class="headerLogo">
            </a>

            <nav>
                <ul class="nav-links">
                    <!-- <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li> -->
                    <li><a href="photography.html">Photography</a></li>
                    <li><a href="graphic-design.html">Graphic Design</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>

                <div class="burger">
                    <div class="line1"></div>
                    <div class="line2"></div>
                    <div class="line3"></div>
                </div>
            </nav>

        </div>
    </header>    

    <br />

    <div class="section">
        <ul class="grid">
            <li>
                <div class="box p-cov1">
                    <a href="concert-photography.html">
                    <div class="info">
                        <h3>Concert Photography</h3>
                    </div></a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="box p-cov2">
                    <a href="light-painting.html">
                    <div class="info">
                        <h3>Light Painting</h3>
                    </div></a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="box p-cov3">
                    <a href="portraits-people.html">
                    <div class="info">
                        <h3>Portraits & People</h3>
                    </div></a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="box p-cov4">
                    <a href="nature.html">
                    <div class="info">
                        <h3>Nature</h3>
                    </div></a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="box p-cov5">
                    <a href="animals.html">
                    <div class="info">
                        <h3>Animals</h3>
                    </div></a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="box p-cov6">
                    <a href="special-events.html">
                    <div class="info">
                        <h3>Special Events</h3>
                    </div></a>
                </div>
            </li>  
        </ul>
    </div>

    <br />
    <br />

    <footer>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/JackiLeighDesigns/" target="_blank">
            <img src="photos/fbicon.png" alt="Facebook Icon" class="fbIcon">
        </a>

        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/jacki_leigh/" target="_blank">    
            <img src="photos/instaicon.png" alt="Instagram Icon" class="instaIcon">
        </a>

        <br />

        <small>copyright &copy; <script type="text/javascript">document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script> Jacki Leigh Designs</small>
        </style>
    </footer>

    <script src="javascript/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #FCFCFC;
    font-family: "operetta 8", serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}

.container { /* logo and text/links in navigation bar */
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.headerLogo { /* logo in navigation bar */
    /* floating logo to the left */
    /* full canvas photo is 2057px wide & 643px in height */
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 0; /* gives a little space on top and bottom of the logo */
    width: 164.56px; /* 8% of the full size (2057px) */
    height: 51.44px; /* 8% of the full size (643px) */
}

header {
    background: #E9E9E9;
    opacity: 1;
}

header::after { 
    /* used because .logo and nav are float left/right, shrinking the container to 0px, this fixes that */
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

nav {
    /* floating list (menu) items to the right */
    float: right;
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0; /* takes space off top and bottom header background */
    padding: 0; /* takes space off the sides */
    list-style: none; /* removes bullet point styling */
}

nav li {
    display: inline-block; /* places list horizontal, not vertical */
    margin-left: 30px; /* specifies the spacd between the list items */
    padding-top: 25px; /* not required - used for the hover effect for this particular nav bar */
    position: relative; /* allows the nav a::before to keep the hover line relative to the text length */
}

nav ul li a {
    color: #7F7887;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 17px;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #3f003c;
}

nav ul li a::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #3f003c;

    position: absolute; /* absolute width 100% shoots this to 100% of the screen size (they run together) */
    top: 0;
    width: 0%;

    transition: all ease-in-out 250ms; /* slows down the way the hover bar appears */
}

nav ul li a:hover::before {
    width: 100%;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.burger {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: static;
    z-index: 200;
}

.burger div {
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #3f003c;
    margin: 5px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease; /* adds transition to Burger turning into an X */
}

.mainLogo {
    /* class for logo/image on index page */
    width: 75%;
    height: 60%;
    opacity: 0.9;
}

.mainLogoDiv {
    /* class for the div containing the logo/image on index page */
    text-align: center;
}

.section {
    max-width: 1920px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1% 2%;
}

.grid {
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.grid:after {
    clear: both;
}

.grid:after, .grid:before {
    content: '';
    display: table;
}

.grid li {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px;
}

.box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out, 
    -webkit-transform 0.3 ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out, 
    -moz-transform 0.3 ease-in-out;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out, 
    transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.box:hover {
    transform: scale(1.05);
}

.p-cov1 {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(65, 41, 63, 0.75), rgba(65, 41, 63, 0.75)),
    url(photos/photography/covers/mj-cover.jpg);
}

.p-cov2 {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(65, 41, 63, 0.75), rgba(65, 41, 63, 0.75)),
    url(photos/photography/covers/lp-cover.jpg);
}

.p-cov3 {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(65, 41, 63, 0.75), rgba(65, 41, 63, 0.75)),
    url(photos/photography/covers/pp-cover.jpg);
}

.p-cov4 {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(65, 41, 63, 0.75), rgba(65, 41, 63, 0.75)),
    url(photos/photography/covers/la-cover.jpg);
}

.p-cov5 {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(65, 41, 63, 0.75), rgba(65, 41, 63, 0.75)),
    url(photos/photography/covers/an-cover.jpg);
}

.p-cov6 {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(65, 41, 63, 0.75), rgba(65, 41, 63, 0.75)),
    url(photos/photography/covers/se-cover.jpg);
}

.g-cov1 {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(65, 41, 63, 0.75), rgba(65, 41, 63, 0.75)),
    url(photos/graphic/covers/dc-cover.jpg);
}

.g-cov2 {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(65, 41, 63, 0.75), rgba(65, 41, 63, 0.75)),
    url(photos/graphic/covers/ww-cover.jpg);
}

.info {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.info h3 {
    font-family: "Operetta 8", serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #e0e0e0;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px black;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 85px 0px 0 0px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 100%;
}

.photoGrid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minMax(250px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 5px 5px;
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
}

.photoColumn {
    display: block;
}

.contact {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.contact-me {
    text-align: center;
}

.contact-me img {
    width: 60%;
    max-width: 450px;
    padding: 10px 0 20px 0;
}

form {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 13.5px;
    padding: 0px 20px 20px 20px; /* gives space on all text contained within border */
    margin: 0 auto;
    line-height: 30px;
    height: 80%;
    width: 70%;
    max-width: 500px;
    overflow: auto;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #3f003c;
}

input[type=submit] {
    background-color: #3f003c;
    color: #E9E9E9;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 35px;
    width: 100px;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* the below syntax removes the blue border in the input boxes when selected */
input:focus, textarea:focus, select:focus {
    outline-offset: 0px !important;
    outline: none !important;
}

/* the two syntaxes below change the color of highlighted text */
::selection {
    background: #E9E9E9; /* WebKit/Blink Browsers */
}

::-moz-selection {
    background: #E9E9E9; /* Gecko Browsers */
}

/* the below set of syntaxes removes the background color when autofill is used */
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active {
    transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px #fff inset;
}

#name {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
}

#email {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
}

#message {
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
}


footer {
    color: #7F7887;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.fbIcon {
    /* class for the facebook icon in the footer */
    padding: 0 2px 8px 0;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    opacity: .7;
}

.instaIcon {
    /* class for the instagram icon in the footer */
    padding: 0 0 8px 0;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 952px) {      
    .nav-links {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
        height: 100%;
        top: 70px;
        background-color: #E9E9E9;
        opacity: .95;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 35%;
        transform: translateX(100vw);
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
        z-index: 100;
    }

    .nav-links li {
        margin-left: 0px;
        opacity: 0;
        padding: 45px 0px 0px 0px;
    }

    .nav-links li a {
        color: #7F7887;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    .nav-links li a:hover {
        color: #3f003c;
    }

    nav ul li a::before {
        display: none;
    }

    .burger {
        display: block;
        padding: 20px;
        z-index: 150;
        position: static;
    }
}

.nav-active {
    transform: translateX(0%);
}

@keyframes navLinkFade {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(50px);
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0px); 
    }
}

/* 3 code blocks below are to set up the hamburger menu to turn into an X once it's been clicked and the menu slides in from the right */

/* this takes the top hamburger line and turns it -45 degrees to form one part of the X */
.toggle .line1 {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px,6px);
}

/* this takes the middle hamburger line and turns it to 0 opacity */
.toggle .line2 {
    opacity: 0;
}

/* this takes the bottom hamburger line and turns it 45 degrees to form the second part of the X */
.toggle .line3 {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px,-6px);
}
```

JavaScript:

```
const navSlide = () => {
    const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
    const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
    const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');

    burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
        //Toggle Nav
        nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');

        //Animate Links
        navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
            if (link.style.animation) {
                link.style.animation = ''
            } else {
                link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 0.5}s`;
            }
        });

        //Burger Animation
        burger.classList.toggle('toggle');
    });

}

navSlide();
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is that you're targeting both the `html` and `body` elements with your scroll settings `@media screen and (max-width: 952px)` - this causes a scroll within a scroll effect, which can be buggy in mobile views.

I was able to fix this in the inspector by removing `html` moving the `body` styles outside of the media query and changing the `transform` line in the `.nav-links` styles from `100%` to `100vw`. They should work the same in this scenario but `vw` (viewport width) seems to work better.

```
    body {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 952px) {
        .nav-links {
            transform: translateX(100vw);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The only issue with that is it causes the horizontal scroll to be enabled, which allows you to scroll to the right and see the empty mobile nav bar when it should be hidden. Any ideas on why that happens?

Comment: Hey Jacki, I didn't encounter the horizontal scroll issue but I updated the styles to represent what I tried (just now), that should work as long as your code is identical to what you have deployed.

Comment: I updated the CSS in my post to reflect what I have right now. I made the changes you mentioned, which were very helpful (THANK YOU!), but I am still having a horizontal scroll issue - only on mobile. it doesn't have that issue on the desktop view. I'm certainly doing something wrong, I just can't figure out what.

Comment: Almost 4 years later, this solved a similar problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my site in Webflow because of `overflow-x: hidden` on `body`. I managed to solve this problem by deleting all styles except `margin: 0` from `body`, then I wrapped all sections on my page with `div` and added it simple `overflow: hidden`.